# RaisedButton fullWith doesn't expand anymore in v0.15

Tags: material-ui

The RaisedButtons components don't go `fullWidth` anymore in the version v0.15 of material-ui, this worked in the v0.15-beta. I solved it by adding  `minWidth: '100%'` to the element. Is this intentional or am I doing something wrong here ?

```
const buttonStyle = {
  minWidth:'100%',//<- works with minWidth set
};
return (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
    <div style={style}>
      <SelectField max-height={200} style={selectStyle} fullWidth={true} onChange={this.onFondsSelect} value={displayValue} id="fonds-selection">
        {this.menuItems}
      </SelectField>
      <RaisedButton style={buttonStyle} onClick={this::this.startClick} fullWidth={true}>Button 1</RaisedButton><br/>
      <RaisedButton style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.resetStart} fullWidth={1}>BUtton 2</RaisedButton>
    </div>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was introduced in material-ui v15
issue => [github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4226](http://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4226)

However as you can see in the issue comments, the `fullWidth` may be deprecated in v16 in favour of the style object. So you are doing it the right way.